# Split string in a dataset to different columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How can I split the string in my dataset to different columns. Below is how my dataset looks like.

| ColumnA |
| --- |
| ABCDEF |
| GHIPQRS |

Below is the expected output. Please note that the string has variable length with no delimiter and has to be split only till the first two characters in the string.

| Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDE | ABCD | ABC | AB |  |
| GHIPQR | GHIPQ | GHIP | GHI | GH |

I'm new to BigQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what this query is for ?

Comment: @Jaytiger I'm working on a scenario where I need to split the unique ID as shown above using BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider a [recursive approach](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/recursive-ctes) like below.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'ABCDEF' ColumnA UNION ALL SELECT 'GHIPQRS'
),
iterations AS (
  SELECT  ColumnA, 1 idx, ColumnA AS SubStr FROM sample_table
   UNION ALL
  SELECT  ColumnA, idx + 1, LEFT(SubStr, LENGTH(SubStr) - 1) 
    FROM iterations WHERE LENGTH(SubStr) > 2
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(ColumnA) FROM iterations
 PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(SubStr) Column FOR idx IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
```

**Query results**

[image]

- See also : [PIVOT query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator)

For a dynamic query,

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS 
SELECT 'ABCDEF' ColumnA UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHIPQRS' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  WITH RECURSIVE iterations AS (
    SELECT  ColumnA, 1 idx, ColumnA AS SubStr FROM sample_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ColumnA, idx + 1, LEFT(SubStr, LENGTH(SubStr) - 1) 
      FROM iterations WHERE LENGTH(SubStr) > 2
  )
  SELECT * EXCEPT(ColumnA) FROM iterations
    PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(SubStr) Column FOR idx IN (%s));
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG('' || idx) 
        FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(ColumnA)) FROM sample_table))) idx
     )
);
```

[image]

Click last `VIEW RESULTS`, then you will see

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jaytiger for this solution. Could you please suggest how can I make this query more dynamic ? Like I mention in my query that the string to be split is varying in length, and in the solution you have provided we are able to display only the first 6 columns, so if my string has more characters, the output won't be as expected.

Comment: To make above query more flexible, you should consider to use a dynamic query.  I've updated the answer with another example. Hope it be helpful.

Comment: I got the expected output @Jaytiger. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: You can ignore the warning and if you run the query as it is in BigQuery console, you can get 3 results from BigQuery since above query is actually a script.  Check the output and find last one from job result.  I've updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to explain @Jaytiger. I got the expected output. Kudos to you :)